# aws transcribe callback function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-transcribe

I want to call AWS transcribe function from an AWS Lambda.

In that lambda handler, I want to start the transcription job but not wait for it to finish in a while loop since it will not be cost-efficient. I don't see any way for the transcription job finish to call another Lambda, or something like that, to store the transcription information in an s3 bucket for example.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Using Amazon EventBridge with Amazon Transcribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/monitoring-events.html).

> With Amazon EventBridge, you can respond to state changes in your Amazon Transcribe jobs by initiating events in other AWS services. When a transcription job changes state, EventBridge automatically sends an event to an event stream. You create rules that define the events that you want to monitor in the event stream and the action that EventBridge should take when those events occur. For example, routing the event to another service (or target), which can then take an action. You could, for example, configure a rule to route an event to an AWS Lambda function when a transcription job has completed successfully.

Another alternative is:

- when you call StartTranscriptionJob, you supply an S3 bucket name and S3 object key that will receive the transcribed results
- you can use the [Amazon S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) feature to notify you or to automatically trigger a Lambda function